# Repeatedly get values from Postgres, using most recent set

Tags: haskell

I have a sensor that reads values into a Postgres DB.  I have a `main :: IO ()` function that returns a list of the values in a given table.  (The example below is for a light sensor that returns a `Bool` for whether the light sensor is exposed to light or not.)

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connectPostgreSQL "my connection string here"
  myQuery <- (query_ conn "select sensor1 from lightbool" :: IO [Only String])
  mapM_ print myQuery
  let usefulLightBools = lightBoolConverter myQuery
  mapM_ print usefulLightBools

lightBoolConverter :: [Only String] -> [Bool]
lightBoolConverter = map (lightBoolString2Bool . read . show . fromOnly)

-- TODO change to a Maybe Bool and fix this pattern matching
lightBoolString2Bool :: String -> Bool
lightBoolString2Bool "TRUE" = True 
lightBoolString2Bool "FALSE" = False
```

I want to have the script periodically (e.g. every 5 seconds), query the database and store the results in a list.  I want to use the latest value of the list as an input for a function until there is a new value to replace it.

The way I thought to implement this was to compare two lists -- the initially-grabbed list and the potentially-new list -- and take the `head` of the `reverse` of the longer list.

```
compareLists :: [a] -> [a] -> a
compareLists l1 l2 = head $ reverse $ maximumBy (comparing length) [l1,l2]
```

I am unclear on how to modify my `main` function to store `usefulLightBools`, periodically re-run the query, store the new query in a different variable (`usefulLightBoolsLatest`?), and use my `compareLists` to get the correct value and store that value in a variable.

Or maybe there is a simpler version where (1) the query is run periodically on some time delay and (2) I do something like this?

```
  let usefulLightBools = reverse $ lightBoolConverter myQuery
  myVar <- head usefulLightBools
```

Comment: It's still not really clear what you're trying to achieve. What's wrong with polling every 5 seconds and doing your action with the latest value each iteration?

Comment: Note that `read . show == id`

Comment: @moonGoose - on second thought, yes that makes sense -- but still wondering how to get `main` to run every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this good enough?

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

main = forever $ do
    bools <- {- ... -}
    print bools
    threadDelay 5000000 -- 5 seconds
```

Query the database, do something neat with the result, wait 5 seconds, rinse, repeat. There are certainly more sophisticated things to do that address shortcomings of this way, but if this meets your needs it definitely has the advantage of being particularly simple.